# DotNetNuke upgrade from 6.02.09 to 7.40.00

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-settings

I am trying to upgrade from DontNetNuke from 6.02.09 to 7.40.00 
The upgrade process is completed successfully.  But when I try to access the website I get the following   error " File Error Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Installed a local version of the DNN 7.4 and then changes the webconfig file and now it works